# Associate checkbox with grid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a grid with a boolean column. I am trying to associate with anothoer checkbox control, so that when i check this checkbox my window displays a elements from grid with boolean column which is true(checked).

here is my IsChecked property

```
      private bool _isChecked;

      public bool IsChecked
    {
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

            InitializeMappedElements();

        }


        get { return _isChecked; }

    }
```

Here is a method that select only mapped elements from grid
         public ObservableCollection MappedList
        {
            get { return _mappedList; }
            set { _mappedList = value; }
        }

```
    private ObservableCollection<MessageFieldViewModel> _mappedList = new ObservableCollection<MessageFieldViewModel>();

     private void InitializeMappedElements()
    {

        if (_isChecked)
        {
            var transactionRuleList =
                MessageFieldVModel.GetAllMessageField().Where(ame => ame.IsMapped == _isChecked);

            _mappedList = new ObservableCollection<MessageFieldViewModel>(transactionRuleList);
            messageFields = _mappedList;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageFields");

        }
    }
```

Associate with Grid on select

```
    public ObservableCollection<MessageFieldViewModel> MessageFields
       {
        set
        {
            if (_isChecked)
            {
                InitializeMappedElements();
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageField");
        }
        get { return messageFields; }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <CheckBox  Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Content="Display only Mapped Fields" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Margin="198,35,473,74" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" 
                   IsChecked="{Binding Path= IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </CheckBox>
```

when i select nothing is showing .why is this not working? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is hard to follow and will be even harder to maintain. Instead of setting the backing field directly, use the `MessageFields` property and set the backing field in the setter as normal.

Having said that though, you should consider using a [CollectionViewSource](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) instead as this sounds like just a concern of the view.

Comment: I found what the problem is I associated the grid with another control so that the grid shows only when i select item from that control. You are right I Need to figure out a way to make my code manageable